# Getx function always looping

Tags: flutter, function, flutter-getx

I create function to get category and initelizeplayer

```
@override
  void onInit() {
    // TODO: implement onInit
    super.onInit();
    ever(konten, (_) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        initializePlayer();
      });
    });
    konten.value = DetailKonten();
    once(konten, (_) {
      updateKonten(konten.value!);
      getCategory();
    });
  }

  @override
  void onReady() {
    // TODO: implement onReady
    super.onReady();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    // Hentikan pemutaran video dan lakukan pembersihan
    videoPlayerController?.dispose();
    super.onClose();
  }
```

i call on init but the function always loop i want just 1 on first open